# Analyze audio (live or recorded) for a specific sound and increment a timer

Tags: macos, mac, audio

I am looking for a way to estimate the amount of time a specific individual spends typing everyday, this individual types extremely loud so catching the audio of the keyboard strokes isn't a problem, and is really the only way I will be able to estimate the amount of time spent typing is through audio as I do not have access to the machine this individual is using.

I am wondering if there is any type of solution that would come close to what I am looking for in this situation.

Any ideas, and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Record everything for the whole day, and edit it down manually in your favorite audio editor to only include the sections in which you hear typing. The resulting recording's length will be the time you seek.

Comment: Why not just ask them to monitor/time it themselves?